# Complex mod proof

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that if $|z| = 1, |w| = 1$ and $\overline{z}w \ne 1$ then $\bigg| \frac{z - w}{1 - \overline{z}w} \bigg| = 1$

So we have two cases, $|z| = 1$ and $|w| = 1$.

**Case 1: |z| = 1**

I'd guess we begin with:

$\bigg| \frac{z - w}{1 - \overline{z}w} \bigg| = \bigg| \frac{z - w}{1 - \overline{z}w} \cdot \frac{\overline{1 - \overline{z}w}}{\overline{1 - \overline{z}w}} \bigg| = \bigg|\frac{(z-w)(1 - z\overline{w})}{(1 - \overline{z}w)(1 - z\overline{w})}\bigg| = \frac{z - z^2\overline{w} + wz + |w|^2}{1 - z\overline{w} - \overline{z}w + |z|^2|w|^2}$

But this doesnt lead me anywhere.

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: why two cases, you need both conditions together.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z = e^{\theta i}, w = e^{\beta i}\implies |z-w| = |e^{\theta i}-e^{\beta i}|= |e^{\theta i}||1-e^{-\theta i}e^{\beta i}|= |1-\bar{z}w|$. This implies the result.